# Help binding Dynamic Map Layer popup in Esri Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, popup, esri-leaflet

I've been experimenting with a web map using [Esri Leaflet](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/customizing-popups.html) examples and I've run into a bit of a problem getting my popups to load. I'm able to successfully load the data from the REST service and it displays properly, however no popup is created when I click each feature.

```
Sites = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer("http://gis.montgomerycountymd.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/General/Fiber_PLOI/MapServer",{});
Sites.bindPopup(function (error, featureCollection) {
if(error || featureCollection.features.length === 0) {
  return false;
} else {
  return 'Name: ' + featureCollection.features.properties.NAME;}
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle? That would help in debugging your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the features property of featureCollection is an array.  Because of this you'd either need to loop through all of them or just specify a static index position if you'd like to get a reference to the first individual feature.

`return 'Name: ' + featureCollection.features[0].properties.NAME;}`

setting a breakpoint within the callback which is triggered by bindPopup is the best way to get a better idea of what exactly is returned and how you can work with it.

Comment: I tried to add a static index but the popups are still not binding.

Comment: works fine for me w/ your service... http://jsfiddle.net/jagravois/aLaokhjg/

Comment: Wow man thanks so much! This has been driving me nuts. Turns out the problem was I was using layer controls, and called the .bindPopup method prior to calling L.control.layers().addTo(map).